# Why do errors occur in programming?

Tags: software-engineering

I like to reduce the number of exceptions raised in my code, and I thought it might help to consider why these exception are raised in the first place, and whether they are a really a fundamental part of code or just an artefact of not really finishing the program.

As a related note I hear OS programming requires avoiding errors where possible, perhaps there are some answers there.

Comment: “Errors” has multiple meanings. Are you talking about errors = mistakes, where the program doesn't do what was intended? Or are you talking about exceptions, which are not necessarily errors in any meaning of the word? Or are you talking about success vs failure, which may be conveyed by exceptions or return codes (or more rarely other means)?

Answer (score 3):

Errors occur in programming because programs are written by humans and humans make errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what type of exceptions you are asking about, but [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) may be relevant.